# Getting the root node of selection in JFace Tree View

Tags: java, treeview, jface

I have a JFace Tree View in which there are many root nodes and each root node has children with many levels. For example

```
 Root 1
     child1
        child1.child1
     child2
        child2.child1

  Root 2
     child1
        child1.child1
     child2
        child2.child1
```

If I click on any child under root 1 I want to get the Root 1 node and if I click on any child under Root 2 I want to get the Root 2 node?

I checked with selection but there is only one method getFirstElement() How can I do that ?

```java
viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {

    TreeViewer viewer = (TreeViewer) event.getViewer();

    IStructuredSelection thisSelection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection(); 

    Object selectedNode = thisSelection.getFirstElement(); 

   viewer.setExpandedState(selectedNode,
        !viewer.getExpandedState(selectedNode));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getParent(Object element)` method of your tree viewer Content Provider to get the parent of an element - so you can move up the tree using that.

You will need to remember your content provider somewhere, or use

```
ITreeContentProvider provider = (ITreeContentProvider)viewer.getContentProvider();
```

where `viewer` is your tree viewer.

It is your responsibility to write the `getParent` method of the content provider.

So your data model classes will have to be created with the information about their parent:

```
class DataModelObject
{
  private DataModelObject parent;

  DataModelObject(DataModelObject parent)
  {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  DataModelObject getParent()
  {
    return parent;
  }
}
```

or just save the root:

```
class DataModelObject
{
  private DataModelObject root;

  DataModelObject(DataModelObject root)
  {
    this.root = root;
  }

  DataModelObject getRoot()
  {
    return root;
  }
}
```

Comment: I implemented a selectionlistener and on the basis of the selected item in the tree I want to find its root node

Comment: Yes well use the content provider or add code to your data model classes. The tree viewer does not have anything that will just give you this.

Comment: What should I add the content provider to the root node?

Comment: @greg-499  Can you please provide me with some pseudo code ?